# what method and way and any technology is there for use GPU for coin-hive mining?

Tags: monerod, gpu-mining

I know about can not use javascript and browser for GPU coin-hive mining...

So now the question is what method and way and any technology or codes is there for use GPU for coin-hive mining? (coinhive.com) (If provide any codes is helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no method to mine from javascript on a GPU. Coinhive (and others) rely on javascript WebAssembly to perform the mining and WebAssembly boils down to just optimized javascript bytecode. The only possible direct access to the GPU from javascript (that I know of) is WebGL, and the access given is not for compute, which is what would be needed for mining.